# MongoDB: top-level array conditions

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, nosql, expression

I have an array of arrays in MongoDB 4.2.2:

```
db.foo.insertOne({'foo': [[1, 3], [2], [3]]})
```

I'd like to remove elements of foo, first elements of which are greater than 1. But I cannot figure out how.

I tried something like this (and many more) but it does not pull anything:

```
db.foo.update({}, {$pull: {foo: {'0': {$gt: 1}}}})
```

Is it possible?

**EDIT:** Expected result:

```
db.foo.find({})
{ "_id": ObjectId("..."), "foo": [ [1, 3] ] }
```

Comment: Can you show what you expect the document to look like after this operation? I think it will help make clear your intent.

Comment: How do you apply "which are greater than 1" on an array? Do you consider the **Array** `[1,3]` greater than 1? If yes, what are the exact conditions for that?

Comment: @JamesWahlin sorry, I've edited my answer.
@WernfriedDomscheit "first elements of which are greater than 1" i.e. I compare the first elements, so `[1, 3]` does not hold the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2, you can make use of a pipeline in the new update.  This allows you to pass an aggregation pipeline as the update argument:

```
db.foo.update({},[
    {$addFields:{
        foo:{
            $filter:{
                input:"$foo",
                cond:{
                    $lte: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 0]}, 1]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
  ])
```

Comment: Great! So the "$$this" keyword can address the top level. Btw, after "$$this" there should be comma instead of period (I cannot edit it because it's only 1 character and I need 6). @Joe, maybe you can?

Comment: wait... it behaves weirdly on some inputs, I need to test it more... Ok, got it, editing your answer.

Comment: and if you want to use a name other than `this`, you can specify an `as` field to the filter with the name you want.

Comment: There are few more incompatibilities with my question, the line should be `$lte: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 0]}, 1]`. My edit was not accepted for some reason, @Joe, could you please fix it so that I could mark your answer again as accepted?